# Series.Format.Fill.Transparency property not applying formatting

Tags: excel, vba, format, transparency, series

I have a chart in which I create a number of new series for using the `Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries` method, there after I immediately format each series. All formatting seems to work (marker size/style/colour) bar marker transparency which I set via the `Series.Format.Fill.Transparency` property.

I have seen people using the selection method to set series marker transparency as per below:

```
 Set GraphSeries.Absolute.ErraticErrors = AbsChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With GraphSeries.Absolute.ErraticErrors
    .Name = "ErraticSeries"
    .MarkerSize = CommonMarkerSize
    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = Graph.XY.Formatting.MarkerFillColour.ErraticErrors
    .MarkerForegroundColor = Graph.XY.Formatting.MarkerLineColur.ErraticErrors
    .Select
        Selection.Format.Fill.Transparency = CommonMarkerTrans
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With
```

After trying and troubleshooting the above method, it seems when the marker transparency is set, the marker background colour can be seen to change value rather than the transparency which remains at its initial value, strange? Based on this finding, I reverted back to `Series.Format.Fill.Transparency = CommonMarkerTrans` and viewed this property in the watch window while setting it to `CommonMarkerTrans`and observed no change to the initial value `of Series.Format.Fill.Transparency` (-2.147484E+09), also strange?

Seems that the `Series.Format.Fill.Transparency` property is not changing from its intial value when trying to set it to `CommonMarkerTrans`via `Series.Format.Fill.Transparency = CommonMarkerTrans`

Note: `CommonMarkerTrans`= 0.9 as single

Anyone have any ideas why this is? I'm really stumped here, could it be related to the ordering in which I am setting the marker formatting?

Below shows a snippet of code to provide context. The code creates an  'empty' chart series and then applies various formatting, such as marker size, and then sets the series X and Y values from data stored in two separate arrays.

```
Set GraphSeries.Absolute.ErraticErrors = AbsChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
With GraphSeries.Absolute.ErraticErrors
    .Name = "ErraticSeries"
    .MarkerSize = CommonMarkerSize
    .Format.Fill.Transparency = CommonMarkerTrans
    .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = Graph.XY.Formatting.MarkerFillColour.ErraticErrors
    .MarkerForegroundColor = Graph.XY.Formatting.MarkerLineColur.ErraticErrors
    .Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
End With

RelOrAbsChart.SeriesCollection(SeriesName.ErraticSeries).XValues = XAxisRelOrAbs.ErraticSeries
RelOrAbsChart.SeriesCollection(SeriesName.ErraticSeries).Values = YAxisRelOrAbs.ErraticSeries
```

Comment: Something like `With ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill` should do the trick. What do you mean exactly by "...it also does not work.". it would be helpful to know the value of `i` Does it match the series you want to format?

Comment: By not working I mean does not set any type of transparency to the series markers, they remain opaque. And yes, I have confirmed I am addressing the correct series from the collection. I use enums to ensure the correct series are addressed and have confirmed that marker style and colour of the series marker are being set correctly, it just seems when I apply a 0.8 transparency to the markers they remain opaque.

Comment: Also, when creating the series I assign the series returned from the .NewSeries method to a variable, let’s say 'x', declared as type Series. I then proceed via x.Select. And apply the formatting by Selection.Format.Fill.Transparency = CommonMarkerTrans. Such that this should ensure the correct seires is formatted (the newly created one). However the markers remain opaque.

Comment: You may want to include that part of your code in your question

Comment: Hi, I did, as soon as you mentioned it.

Comment: @Mitchell this is a terrific write-up to the problem I am trying to solve. Did you find any resolution? It's killing me :)

Comment: Hi @JoshMarks, this was a while ago, but if you analyse the differences between the two code snippets you should be able to deduce the solution. From my memory, I believe I had to use a different method to set the background/foreground colour of the chart series to what I was originally, if I wanted the ability to set the transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I may have solved this. For some reason you must use the following properties to set for/background colour of series markers if you want to use `Fromat.Fill. Transparency` to set the marker Transparency

```
 Series.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(R,G,B)
 Series.Format.Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(R,G,B)
```

And not

```
Series.MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(R,G,B)
Series.MarkerForegroundColor = RGB(R,G,B)
```

Not sure why this is the case, seems confusing to have two separate properties to set Marker for/background colour and not be able to set transparency for both.

Why would you need two separate and mutually exclusive properties for the same thing? For clarity, maybe someone could clear this up or correct my understanding?

Functioning code which now sets colour and transparency correctly:

```
    Set GraphSeries.Absolute.ErraticErrors = AbsChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With GraphSeries.Absolute.ErraticErrors
        .Name = "ErraticSeries"
        .MarkerSize = CommonMarkerSize
        .MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleCircle
        With .Format.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.RGB = Graph.XY.Formatting.MarkerFillColour.ErraticErrors
            .BackColor.RGB = Graph.XY.Formatting.MarkerLineColur.ErraticErrors
            .Transparency = CommonMarkerTrans
            .Visible = msoTrue
        End With
    End with
```